# Go to another activity on Menu Item Selection Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, menuitem

Hello I have problem with going to another activity by MenuItem. I don't where is the problem with my code, because Android Studio tell that is problem with intent. I Imported intent already at the bottom of kotlin class. I saw tutorials, but there is still a problem with a code.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == R.id.btn_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class)
                    this.startActivity(intent)
        }
        
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a mixed java/kotlin code .. `new` is a java keyword. Use the below instead

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId
    if (id == R.id.btn_settings) {
        val intent = Intent(
            this, SettingActivity::class.java)
        startActivity (intent)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Ok, Android studio don't give an error, but now application is crashing when I am trying to open app :/

Comment: @PatrykKwiatkowski Can you update the question with the crash stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake but now i have problem with navigation menu. When onOPtionsItemSelcted is in the code navigation drawer isn't working. When I remove this fragment navigation drawer is back.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.View
import android.content.Intent


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_paliwo, R.id.nav_naprawa, R.id.nav_wydatki, R.id.nav_oc,R.id.nav_pt), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)


            return true

    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == R.id.btn_settings) {
            val intent = Intent(
                    this, SettingsActivity ::class.java)
            startActivity (intent)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
    }
```